# Безопасность Internationalization django

Tags: python, django, безопасность

Возник вопрос безопасности при реализации мультиязычности проекта на `django`.

Сомнения возникают при понимании того, что перевод хранится и изменяется в файлах с расширениями `.po` и `.mo`. То есть, так или иначе есть необходимость в изменении файлов в файловой системе проекта.

Даже если взять на вооружение `django-rosetta` модуль, который рекомендует использование отдельной роли для переводчиков, все равно доступ к файловой системе через удаленный доступ - не есть хорошо.

Насколько безопасно использование Internationalization для django из коробки?

Существуют ли реализации основанные на хранении данных переводов в базе данных?

Comment: В боевом окружении должны быть только готовые mo файлы, и доступ к ним только на чтение. Точно такой же доступ, как к обычным файлам проекта, например.

Comment: Прямого доступа к файловой системе боевого окружения в принципе не должно быть ни у кого. Переводчики правят po как будто это исходный код, дальше это через ci/cd "компилируется" в mo и выкатывается на прод.

Comment: @insolor следовательно rosetta изначально идет по не правильному пути и делать жизнь переводчикам легче и предоставлять доступ в удобочитаемом варианте не выход? Действия должны быть такими: создаю .po файлы в среде devops, открываю доступ только к ним для переводчиков, далее собираю .mo и выкатываю на прод?

Comment: po файл - это условно файл исходного кода. Он правится или вручную в исходниках проекта, как любой другой файл исходного кода (обычным текстовым редактором или специализированным редактором, типа poedit), либо используется какой-нибудь сервис перевода (типа transifex, crowdin, или standalone решений), который интегрируется с github/gitlab etc. Сам перевод выкатывается на прод точно так же как если вы релизите изменения в остальном коде.

Comment: Я не понял проблемы. Зачем вообще давать кому-либо доступ к файловой системе? Кто хочет обновить перевод — как минимум шлёт пулл-реквест в git-репозиторий, как максимум использует специальный сервис перевода вроде Weblate (который потом автоматически зашлёт коммит в тот же git-репозиторийй)

Comment: @andreymal искал решение для удобного использования переводчиками. Rosetta модуль дает удобный интерфейс для перевода-правки, но после осознания как происоходит процесс через данный модуль и возник собственно вопрос. Корректность самого перевода мне не проверить, а вот чтобы не возникало кучи вопросов у переводчиков, хотел облегчить им доступ и разгрузить себя от лишних движений

Comment: Из удаленного ответа @VitaliyRyzhyi: на Crowdin есть статья [Django i18n: Agile Localization for Developers](https://crowdin.com/blog/2021/11/10/django-translation) где расписано как можно организовать перевод для Django.